# SSIS Data Integration - Data flow

Tags: ssis, data-integration

I have 4 steps say 1,2,3,4,5 in SSIS script.The steps 4 and 5 are depedent on 2, hence it starts once the step 2 is completed. Steps 2 and 3 are independent. 
Normally when the execution begins the step 1 is started and once it is done, step2 and step3 are parallely executed. This is how I have given the flow.
Step 3 takes more time to finish the process than step2. Once the step2 is done, Steps 4 and 5 will be starting. My problem now is even though step2 is finished, the child steps 4 and 5 are not even starting.
but they are started once the step3 is finished. It seems both the child steps start to execute when the step3 is executed. but there is no flow from step 3 to step 4 & 5. What is the catch here. Step2 waits for step3 to get completed. These are independent steps and both have different sources as well. How do I fix this issue? or what would have caused this issue?

```
Step1
 |_________
 |         |
 Step2   Step3
 |_______
 |       |
 Step4 Step5
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the flow here?

Comment: I have modified my post. Is that fine?

Comment: I have create 5 WorkFlows (which every of them had pause). Step3 had longest pause time. And so as expected Step3 finished last. So it is something with your code.I think we need more info (what components you use ...)

Comment: Can you move the Control flow components around?  Sometimes the precedent constraints go invisible and moving the components will repaint them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karthi,

You need to revisit all the constraints to make sure Step 4 and 5 depends only on successful completion of Step 2.
I have reproduced your scenario and the package is executing Steps 4 and 4 regardless of 3.

Comment: HI William, I was just exploring the SSIS some time back and figured out something which is, whenever I launch the SSIS package, the above said condition happens then I stop the execution and re-run the package  this works normally as you mentioned.  Am confused now to debug. Is there any threads is getting blocked. I could n't figure Why it is behaving as I posted in the first time and works well during the re-run.

Comment: Hi Karthi, that apparent non-deterministic behavior may be the result of the use of Package Configurations along with expressions, especially if somebody else wrote it. Have a look to Package Configurations, your package may be writing and reading something that affects an expression in your data flow, so it would be a good idea to check the constraints (double-click on them) and make sure their evaluation operation are only based on constraints and not expressions.

Comment: BTW, you can add/delete breakpoints by selecting a component and pressing F9, then run the package and use the "Locals" and "Watch" windows to see variable's values. If you want you can Edit Breakpoints to specify under what condition a specific breakpoint breaks (OnPreexecute, OnPostExecute, etc). You should also enable the Thread window, adding the "Suspended Count" column, in order to determine what steps are holding back.